# How to shrink wrap main content on centered 3 column faux layout with sticky footer

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer, multiple-columns

I started out from [this sample CSS template](http://www.css-lab.com/demos/3col-fluid/3col-mm-stickfoot.html) that provides a sticky footer with a centered 3 column faux layout. The 2 side columns are fixed width and the main content is supposed to be shrink wrapped to fit the size of its content, but instead is stretching to the `max-width` value defined in the CSS for the wrapper. The main content is stretching out because the CSS doesn't contain any styles which cause shrink wrapping (i.e. "`display:inline`", "`display:inline-block`", "`float:left`", "`display:table`", "`display:inline-table`", etc...). And lastly, the wrapper contains everything except the sticky footer.

I tried setting the wrapper with `display:table` to shrink wrap the main content, which it did, but now the footer which is outside the wrapper `div`, has incorrect width. It was previously matching its width the same way the wrapper was by defaulting to the `max-width` style it had set which matched the same `max-width` sytle on the wrapper. I'm no CSS expert, but also tried moving the sticky footer inside the wrapper using an alternate sticky footer technique, but then I had colliding CSS styles required for the faux columns with the styles required for having a sticky footer inside the wrapper. I don't know maybe it can be done that way, but from my initial "quick" test, it got messy.

I would prefer not to size it with javascript and instead get it working with CSS if that's possible. Any ideas with CSS?

And [here's a fiddle of it](http://jsfiddle.net/johntrepreneur/aFpey/) without adding the "display:table" to the wrapper CSS. Add that and then the problems begin.

Comment: A fiddle with the code would be helpful.

Comment: @mikevoermans Done, see fiddle above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is this: [Perfect 3 column](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm) It will also resize as you want it with the broswer.